# Remove polish accents in Woocommerce shipping address

Tags: php, wordpress, replace, woocommerce, diacritics

I have a shop on Wordpress with Woocommerce. I want to auto remove polish accents like `ą, ś, ć, ...` to `a, s, c, ...`  in the shipping address.  I want to change for example:  Łukasz to Lukasz.

I found this function in wordpress:

```
<?php remove_accents( $string ) ?>
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_accents

But I don't know how to use it and what file I should edit.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague, but if you are suggesting that you would like to remove the accents from an input field where the user typed them in, then I would place the variable that represents that input in the parentheses.

So for example if there is an input field where people fill in their name and you recover that field using:

```
$name=mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['name']);
```

then you would put `$name` as the item you would like to convert to ASCII, so it would look like this:

```
<?php remove_accents($name) ?>
```